# WebSite and iPhone prototype

Tags: java, javascript, css, iphone, html

I'm developing a web application using J2EE for the backend and HTML, CSS and JS for the frontend. 
What I have to do is to allow users to make something like "prototype" iPhone applications via my webapp.
I said "something like" because it's not a complete prototype. I want to give my users some application screen (that differs each other for some detail: one has an image on the top, another has no images, ...) from which he can choose and then he will be able to personalize this view: maybe change the background image or the text displayed maintaining the same pattern.

I hope I was clear enough

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. I used a framework called Framework7 to simulate a real iOS7 application and then modify it using simple CSS and JS.